# SQLite: insert OR update and get field value causes performance hit

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I create the table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc (abcID INTEGER, primeK TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, b INTEGER)
```

Also I build other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ref0 (abcID INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ref1 (abcID INTEGER)
.
.
.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS refn (abcID INTEGER)
```

Later I want to :

> 1. create new table *refnn* (abcID INTEGER)
> 2. insert number of records into *abc*
> 3. for every record -
>
>    > 3.1 generate new abcID
>    >      3.2 if a record with given **primeK** already exists then I want to retrieve the   existing field *abcID* and put it into *refnn*;
>    >      3.3 Otherwise - put generated *abcID* to *refnn*

Table *abc* is indexed by all of its values

NOTE: table *refn* may contain multiple unique references to records from *abc* and each record from *abc* may be included in *refn*

I found that when I do not retrieve the existing *abcID* value then the UPDATE performs fast enough.
When I add SELECT statement to retrieve the *abcID* then the performance deteriorate severely.
How can I achieve these goals without significant performance hit?

Comment: Why are you creating ref<n> tables? Just create a column called `ref` in table `abc` and enter relevant data in `ref` column. It might be better to use a different field as primary instead of TEXT field. Have you also thought about auto incrementing abcID (https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)?

Comment: Forgot to mention: table *refn* may contain multiple unique references to records from *abc* and each record from *abc* may be included in *refn*

Comment: In that case, you could create a table with reference and abcID combination. That way both tables are normalized to some extent.

Comment: I know.But this appears to be terrible slow solution for bulk insertion.

Comment: What programming language are you using to do bulk insertion?

Comment: Have you tried using a transaction when entering data or any of the methods talked about in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite) question?

Comment: yes, I use transactions, also I configured memory, journal, synch settings to maximum speed. But I have really heavy updates, up to 1M records (which I divide to 100K portions) that may be associated with 1 or more refn tables so every additional query in insertion cycle causes very distinct impact.